# Enemy mouse hover tooltip

Tags: rimworld

I don't have any idea what those values written in the tool-tip are.
Its written :

> shot by Liefe: 44%
>
> shooter 59%
>
> weapon 74%
>
> target size 200% (I guess this is the size of centipede)
>
> weather 50%

also I need to mention that when I deselect Liefe those values in the tool-tip removed.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's your chance to hit with the selected character, followed by the things modifying your chance to hit.

shot by Liefe: 44% <-- the selected character, Liefe, has a 44% chance to hit

shooter 59% <-- Liefe has a 59% chance to hit on their own, based on their Shooting skill (I think range is factored here, as well).

weapon 74%  <-- the weapon Liefe is using reduces his chance to hit by about one-fourth.  This could be due to natural accuracy (SMGs aren't as accurate as rifles), craftsmanship (awful and poor weapons reduce it, good and better weapons increase it).  (Range *might* be factored here, instead.)

target size 200% <-- the size of the thing you're aiming at is doubling your chance to hit, which probably means it's a lot bigger than a person

weather 50% <-- weather is blocking visibility, halving your chance to hit.  I'm guessing fog, but night and precipitation also modify this.